# converting date time to string

Tags: c#, datetime, time

I have a string variable `st` and i have assign this string variable to output coming form data table by using this statement

```
string st;

if(dt!=null)
{
    if(dt.rows.count> 0)
    {
        st = dt.Rows[3]["timeslot_StartTime"].ToString();
    }
}
```

now i want to convert this string variable to date time property and i have done this one by using the below statement

```
DateTime pt1 = DateTime.Parse(st);
```

but it shows error at st saying that `use of unassigned local varaible "st"`.

Comment: Where in your code did you put the line that is giving the error?

Comment: Give us all of the relevant code. It seems like your `st` is might be out of scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are using the variable in a different scope from the one where it's assigned, like

```
string st;
if (condition) {
    st = dt.Rows[3]["timeslot_StartTime"].ToString();
}
DateTime pt1 = DateTime.Parse(st);
```

So, `st` is not always initialized (it is only if the if condition is verified). Try instead

```
string st;
if (condition) {
    st = dt.Rows[3]["timeslot_StartTime"].ToString();
    DateTime pt1 = DateTime.Parse(st);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Initialize `st` to null or string.Empty

```
string st = null;
```

and to be on the safer side, check `st` for null before parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Give `st` an initial value such as

```
string st = String.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

try definning st in this way

```
string st = ""
```

Answer (score 1):

try to do that

```
string st = null;
```

check the st if it's not null before parsing

Answer (score 0):

You only assign `st` inside your `if` logic. If you are attempting to use `st` outside of these blocks, you will run into the "unassignment" error.

Either

- Give the variable a default value when you initialize it

  - something that is parse-able, or remember to include a check before you attempt to parse
- or attempt to parse it to a `DateTime` at the point where you retrieve the value from the data table

Of course, given that you are pulling the value from a DataTable, if the value is *already stored in the table as a date*, forget the `ToString()` and parsing altogether.

```
DateTime date = (DateTime)dt.Rows[x]["ColumnName"];
```

Comment: hi how to check the present time is in between two given times that is in datetime not in string

Comment: @user, please do not ask questions in comments. If you have something that is related to the original, add it into the original. However, your question here appears to be a different piece of logic, so it should be its own *new* question. But for the sake of getting you started, compare that a given date is greater than a start date and less than an end date. Such as `bool isBetween = (startDate <= yourDate) && (yourDate <= endDate);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the string. Right now any initialization or assignment is being performed within an if block. The compiler is detecting this and considering it possibly never initialized.

```
string st = string.Empty;
```

As a side note, it is much safer to use the sister methods TryParse() for conversations to ensure that you won't have any unexpected exceptions thrown due to a invalid formatting issue.
The method will return true if it is converted successfully, which makes a clean look as such:

```
        if (dt!=null)
        {
           if(dt.rows.count> 0)
           {
              st = dt.Rows[3]["timeslot_StartTime"].ToString();
           }
        }

        DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(st, out dt))
        {
            //was successful and do something here
        }
```