# Python Convert a Date Time to just Time

Tags: python, datetime

I have a field that shows time as `1900-01-01 00:05:00` but I want to show it as just `00:05:00` i.e. just five minutes.

I have been looking at the python documentation and it is driving me crazy. From the question [How do I find the time difference between two datetime objects in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345827/how-do-i-find-the-time-difference-between-two-datetime-objects-in-python) it looks like is should be something do with `timedelta` but I am not getting any closer to a solution. The question [Converting Date/Time to Just Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28118259/converting-date-time-to-just-time) suggests you can just use a `format` tag but that is not working for me.  I also looked at [converting date time to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6427806/converting-date-time-to-string) without success, I know this is something simple but I have looked at hundreds of pages looking for something simple. All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the `time` method? If it's a datetime, it should have that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Say you have a `Datetime` object `now`:

`now.time().strftime('%H:%M:%S')`

Answer (score 14):

Load the string with [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) and get the [`time()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time) component:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> s = "1900-01-01 00:05:00"
>>> dt = datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
>>> dt.time().isoformat()
'00:05:00'
```

Here we are dumping the time with [`isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.isoformat) in [ISO 8601 format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Times), but you can also dump the `datetime.time` back to string with [`strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.time.strftime):

```
>>> dt.time().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
'00:05:00'
```